# Using IMEX=1 in SSIS excel 12.0 connection manager causes export to fail

Tags: ssis, excel-2007

I'm using SSIS VS 2008 to export a bunch of data to an Excel 2007 file.  I've used the IMEX=1 option many times in the past to export data to excel 2003 files with great success.  For some reason though, this time when I add it to the connection string it falls over at the export step.  If I take it out, everything works like a champ.  with the exception that the data looks all crappy.

Has anyone run into this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IMEX=1 option tells the driver to use Import mode.  Is there a reason you would use this on an export?  Have you tried using IMEX=0 which tells the driver to use Export mode?